# Javascript удалить слушатель событий

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

Не понимаю, как удалить слушатели.

Вот Html:

```
        <div class="raiting-items">
            <input type="radio" class="raiting-item" value="1" name="raiting">
            <input type="radio" class="raiting-item" value="2" name="raiting">
            <input type="radio" class="raiting-item" value="3" name="raiting">
            <input type="radio" class="raiting-item" value="4" name="raiting">
            <input type="radio" class="raiting-item" value="5" name="raiting">
        </div>
```

Вот Javascript с комментариями:

```
function setRaiting(raiting) {
            const raitingItems = raiting.querySelectorAll('.raiting-item');

            for (let i = 0; i < raitingItems.length; i++) {
                const raitingItem = raitingItems[i];
                raitingItem.addEventListener("mouseenter", mouseEnter);
                raitingItem.addEventListener("mouseleave", mouseLeave);
                raitingItem.addEventListener("click", sendServer);
            }
            function mouseEnter(e) {
                console.log(e.target);
                initRaitingVars(raiting);
                setRaitingActiveWidth(e.target.value);
            }
            function mouseLeave(e) {
                initRaitingVars(raiting);
                setRaitingActiveWidth();
            }

            function sendServer(e) {
                for (let i = 0; i < raitingItems.length; i++) {
                    e.target.removeEventListener("click", clickListener);
                    e.target.removeEventListener("mouseenter", mouseEnterListener);
                    e.target.removeEventListener("mouseleave", mouseLeaveListener);
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: [.removeEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)

Comment: Разве я не по мануалу удаляю? Думаете я не читал? Помощник, конечно, из вас...

Comment: `{ handleEvent: mouseEnter, raiting, value: raitingItem.value }` - в такой записи вы передаете объект, надо тот же самый объект использовать при `removeEventListener`.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko Вы 100% правы, но проблема в том, что у меня слушатели динамически формируются, и вынести из цикла объект слушателя я не могу.

Comment: @Артем, не нужно переходить на оскорбления. Раз вы читали документацию, то думаю понимаете, что вам требуется передать для удаление тоже самое, что вы передавали для слушателя. Если это не выходит сделать, т.к. у вас "динамические слушатели" (как вы выразились), то нужно продумать момент о хранение этих динамических данных. К тому же предлагаю добавить в вопрос инфо о том, зачем такое действие делать и почему нельзя использовать [делегирование событий](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation)

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko, я ни в коем случае Вас не оскорблял, но и получить ответ со ссылкой на "гугл" никак не хотел, т.к. пишу сюда в крайнем случае (после минимум 2-3 дней как не могу справиться с задачей).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В метод `removeEventListener` вторым аргументом нужно передать ту же самую функцию или объект, которые передавались в методе `addEventListener`. У вас при добавлении события вторым аргументом передается объект, а при удалении - функция.

Нужно вынести объекты в отдельные переменные и передавать их в оба обработчика.

Перед циклом:

```
const mouseEnterListener = { handleEvent: mouseEnter, raiting, value: raitingItem.value };
const mouseLeaveListener = { handleEvent: mouseLeave, raiting };
const clickListener = { handleEvent: sendServer, raiting, value: raitingItem.value, raitingItems };
```

В цикле при добавлении слушателя передавать эти объекты:

```
raitingItem.addEventListener("mouseenter", mouseEnterListener);
raitingItem.addEventListener("mouseleave", mouseLeaveListener);
raitingItem.addEventListener("click", clickListener);
```

Для удаления слушателей с одного элемента можно сделать так:

```
function sendServer(e) {
    e.target.removeEventListener("mouseenter", mouseEnterListener);
    e.target.removeEventListener("mouseleave", mouseLeaveListener);
    e.target.removeEventListener("click", clickListener);
}
```

Comment: Это ценный ответ, безусловно! Однако, вы предложили вынести объект слушателя за пределы цикла, НО именно в цикле формируются аргументы для обработчика. Не понимаю как это обойти.  У меня несколько таких рейтингов (по 5 слушателей в каждом), и у каждого item после цикла получается свой слушатель.

Comment: Это ценный ответ, безусловно! Однако, вы предложили вынести объект слушателя за пределы цикла, НО именно в цикле формируются аргументы для обработчика. Не понимаю как это обойти.  У меня несколько таких рейтингов (по 5 слушателей в каждом), и у каждого item после цикла получается свой слушатель. Т.е. ```const clickListener = { handleEvent: sendServer, raiting, value: raitingItem.value, raitingItems };```   ```value: raitingItem.value``` я получаю в теле цикла.

Comment: @Артем value можно получить в функции через e.target.value

Comment: Действительно, этот момент упустил. `value: raitingItem.value` объекте-слушателе не нужен. Внутри обработчика `e` как раз и будет содержать `raitingItem`

Comment: Тогда вообще теряется смысл передавать слушателем объект - проще сразу обработчик (т.к. не привязывается ничего). Пришлось отредактировать код вверху, т.к сюда не вмещается. Но слушатель не удаляется сволочь!

Comment: @Артем ну так ты в примере подписываешься на одни функции, а пытаешься удалить другие

Comment: @Артем если у итема только эти слушатели, и они другими не становятся нигде, то запишите их напрямую в элемент, как если бы он был объектом. Просто присвойте ему три этих функции в ключи. И потом при снятии слушателей просто возьмите их из элемента. Только не забудьте удалить потом у элемента эти ключи. Элемент всегда может быть использован как носитель информации, за исключением случаев когда он затирается новым html.

Comment: @Алексей точно. Запарился..